# Errors when including one header into my MVS project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm trying to include a h file into my project and I'm finding some errors. The program was working correctly. I really need the H file that I have included,
I even tried to change some stuff but still, the same problems are in my projects.

The source of problems are listed in bold writing.

The code is above.

```
class AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE : public CNoTrackObject { public:
AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE();
virtual ~AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE();

// current CWinThread pointer
CWinThread* m_pCurrentWinThread;

// list of CFrameWnd objects for thread
CTypedSimpleList<CFrameWnd*> m_frameList;

// temporary/permanent map state
DWORD m_nTempMapLock;           // if not 0, temp maps locked
CHandleMap* m_pmapHWND;
CHandleMap* m_pmapHMENU;
CHandleMap* m_pmapHDC;
CHandleMap* m_pmapHGDIOBJ;
CHandleMap* m_pmapHIMAGELIST;

// thread-local MFC new handler (separate from C-runtime)
_PNH m_pfnNewHandler;

#ifndef _AFX_NO_SOCKET_SUPPORT
// WinSock specific thread state
HWND m_hSocketWindow;
#ifdef _AFXDLL
CEmbeddedButActsLikePtr<CMapPtrToPtr> m_pmapSocketHandle;
CEmbeddedButActsLikePtr<CMapPtrToPtr> m_pmapDeadSockets;
CEmbeddedButActsLikePtr<CPtrList> m_plistSocketNotifications;
#else
CMapPtrToPtr* m_pmapSocketHandle;
CMapPtrToPtr* m_pmapDeadSockets;
CPtrList* m_plistSocketNotifications;
#endif
#endif

// common controls thread state
CToolTipCtrl* m_pToolTip;
CWnd* m_pLastHit;       // last window to own tooltip
INT_PTR m_nLastHit;         // last hittest code
```

> **TOOLINFO* m_pLastInfo;    // last TOOLINFO structure**

```
INT_PTR m_nLastStatus;      // last flyby status message
CControlBar* m_pLastStatus; // last flyby status control bar
};

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600)
#ifndef _WINSOCK2API_
#ifdef _WINSOCKAPI_
```

> **#error MFC requires use of Winsock2.h**

```
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#endif
```

...

As for the The errors are as follow:

```
- 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxstat_.h(172): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

- 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxstat_.h(172): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

- 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxstat_.h(172): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

- 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h(112):  fatal error C1189: #error :  MFC requires use of Winsock2.h
```

Comment: Please show us _your_ code, not the system header file. It's more likely some problem in the code before this system header file is included.

Comment: The problems are in the two bold lines, and not in my cpp files. Those problems have been showing up as soon as I just write at the top of my cpp file #include ... and those three problems appear.

Comment: The error _manifests_ in a system header file, but it's not _in_ the system header file. Much likely you missed a semicolon before this header file was included.

Comment: I ve checked once again and nothing was missing unfortunately.
MFC requires use of Winsock2.h ??? Do you know how can I sort out that problem?

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted has neither include guards nor `#pragma once` nor included headers or forward declarations, so I assume that it is not complete. Therefore this is a bit guesswork here, but maybe it helps:

- The first Problem seems to be that the compiler does not know what `TOOLINFO` is - maybe there is some include missing or you somehow messed up namespaces, `#defines` or other things befor that header got included.
- The second problem is that you have directly or indireclty included `Winsock.h` before which conflicts with `Winsock2.h` that has to be used for MFC.

Conclusion: It's pretty safe to say that you messed up the code somewhere, but the errors show much later in the included headers and don't seem related to the original cause of the mess.